# How to get two zeros after decimal value

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have 3 columns in gridview ( Qty,Price,Amount ) but in gridview by default cellvalue property is there  to set how many zeros you want after number like if you enter 200 result (200.00).

but am having textbox where am displaying Total so i want the same functionality here also means if total is 1500 it should show 1500.00.

I tried in this way                                     txt_netamount.Text.PadLeft(2,'0'),                                                  but its not working.
Any help

Comment: Front end or backend?

Comment: You could at least have guessed that `PadLeft` will not add anything to the *right* side of your value ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with  `txt_netamount.Text = decimalValue.ToString("0.00");`

Answer (score 0):

```
column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##"
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a `double` with 2 trailing zeroes you can use the following.

```
double myPrice = 1500;

Console.WriteLine("{0:c}", myPrice); //will display $1500.00
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", myPrice); //will display 1500.00
```

The `{0:c}` will format the parameter as a currency (based on the system settings) when displayed.
The `{0:0.00}` will format the parameter with two trailing zeroes.

If you need to change the `Text` attribute of a `Textbox` and add the trailing zeroes you would do the following:

```
int netAmount = 200;

private void txt_netAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_netAmount.Text = netAmount.ToString("0.00");
    }

//this will display as 200.00
```

If you want a few more options for the display see the following:

```
txt_Advance.Text = netAmount.ToString("$.00"); //will display $200.00
txt_Advance.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", netAmount); //will display currency symbol based on computer's culture setting
```

Comment: Hello

I have this below code so how to get two zeros after a number in NetAMount, Advance, Balance field like (200 = 200.00)

 `private void txt_Advance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Advance.TextChanged += txt_Advance_TextChanged;
            int netAmount;
            int.TryParse(txt_netamount.Text + ".00", out netAmount);
            //txt_netamount.Text = decimalValue.ToString("{0:00}");            
            int Advance;
            int.TryParse(txt_Advance.Text, out Advance);
            txt_balance.Text = (netAmount - Advance).ToString();
       }`

Comment: @user2641675 I have edited my answer with more information due to your comment.

Comment: Thanks Matt, But still am not getting value in one textbox This is my code ' if (tot == 0){ }  txt_netamount.Text = tot.ToString("0.00");'    'private void txt_Advance_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Advance.TextChanged += txt_Advance_TextChanged;            
            int netAmount;
            int.TryParse(txt_netamount.Text, out netAmount);           
            int Advance;            
            int.TryParse(txt_Advance.Text, out Advance);                     
            txt_balance.Text = (netAmount- Advance).ToString("N2");         
       }'

Comment: @user2641675 Which Textbox is not getting the value? That code has a few Textboxes.

Comment: I have three textbox Netamount, Advance, Balance. So in Netamount and Balance am getting value but in Advance am not able to enter any value         `txt_netamount.Text = tot.ToString("0.00");`                                                      `txt_balance.Text = (netAmount - Advance).ToString("0.00")`

Comment: @user2641675 you are not giving enough information to figure out your additional issue. Also, the original question has been answered. Please select an answer. If you have an additional question, post another question. In the SO community each question should be limited to a single issue.

Comment: Hello, Can you please check this link I have posted my question here?         `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44a1737-c77d-4f28-9b85-12c7467dbff7/how-to-get-two-zeros-after-decimal-value?forum=winforms`

Comment: @user2641675 I will gladly help you. You need to help the SO community by selecting an answer. This lets other know which answered aided you the most with the posted question. The posted question has been answered.